# Which freeze date for Debian corresponds to the kernel?

Tags: debian

Debian lists three phases for their freeze,

> - 2021-01-12 - Milestone 1 - Transition and (build-)essential Freeze
> - 2021-02-12 - Milestone 2 - Soft Freeze
> - 2021-03-12 - Milestone 3 - Hard Freeze - for key packages and packages without autopkgtests
> - TBA - Milestone 4 - Full Freeze

Which one of these freeze dates corresponds to the Kernel Freeze Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is a [key package](https://udd.debian.org/cgi-bin/key_packages.yaml.cgi), so technically its freeze date is milestone 3.

It is however likely that the kernel will benefit from one or more unblocks, to fix bugs and ensure that the Debian 11 release has as recent a kernel as possible (in the series chosen for Debian 11).